# Partial match (pmatch) not working on shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny, match, shinyapps

I've been working on a web scraping app for gathering some information from JSTOR. The app works fine locally, but it does not work when deployed at shinyapp.io.

The idea is simple, the app downloads html pages (like this: https://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=example&acc=off&wc=on&fc=off&group=none) and read the list by the side where information about the number of hits for each discipline can be found.

```
webpage <- read_html(filePath)
hits_html <- html_nodes(webpage, 'li')
hits <- html_text(hits_html)
```

To make a data frame, the app uses a list of the disciplines to select through partial match the text information from the webpage. This produces the index of the selected discipline in the list of disciplines of the webpage as follows:

```
disciplines <- list("\r\n                African American Studies",
                    "\r\n                African Studies",
                    "\r\n                Agriculture",
                    "\r\n                American Studies",
                    "\r\n                Anthropology",
                    "etc...")

index <- pmatch(disciplines[[i]], hits)

string <- hits[index]
```

The string with the selected discipline is transformed in a numeric in the following manner:

```
begin<-regexpr("\\(", string)
end<-regexpr("\\)", string)
        
k<-substring(string, begin+1, end-1)
k<-sub(",", "", k)
k<-as.numeric(k)
```

This works fine locally, but it does not work on shinyapps.io. After several tests, I noticed that the problem is with the function pmatch (or with any matching that I've tried). Matching functions return NA when used in shinyapps.io, while they work just fine locally. I've already tried some of the follwoing alternatives:

```
index <- pmatch(disciplines[[t]], as.list(hits)) # DOES NOT WORK ON SHINYAPPS.IO
index <- pmatch(disciplines[[t]], hits) # DOES NOT WORK ON SHINYAPPS.IO
index <- which(stringr::str_detect(hits, disciplines[[t]]))[[1]] # DOES NOT WORK ON SHINYAPPS.IO
index <- sjmisc::str_find(hits, disciplines[[t]])[[1]] # DOES NOT WORK ON SHINYAPPS.IO
```

Has someone ever faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur! It seems related to the line separation you are using as expected result. This result with "\r\n" will match only the HTML got by running it in a Windows environment. If your server is a Unix-based one, it won't match, as the line separation is "\n" there.

Try to remove the \r from the expected result and re-run your application.